# Write to ofstream followed by read with ifstream doesn't read entire file

Tags: c++, ifstream, ofstream

The following program writes 100 bytes, but doesn't read them all back. Why?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <vector>
#include <climits>
#include <algorithm>
#include <map>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>

int main()
{
    constexpr size_t file_size{100};
    std::random_device r{};
    auto min = std::numeric_limits<unsigned char>::min();
    auto max = std::numeric_limits<unsigned char>::max();
    std::uniform_int_distribution<size_t> ud{min,max};

    {
        std::ofstream ofs{"otp.bin",std::ios::binary};
        for(size_t i{}; i < file_size; ++i) {
            ofs << static_cast<unsigned char>(ud(r));
        }
        ofs.close(); // not needed? 
    }

    std::ifstream ifs{"otp.bin",std::ios::binary};

    unsigned char c{};
    size_t i{};
    while(ifs >> c) {
        std::cout << std::setw(4) << std::hex << static_cast<unsigned int>(c) << std::dec << ((++i % 10 == 0) ? '\n' : ' ');
    }

    std::cout << '\n' << i << " bytes read.\n";
    return 0;
}
```

I sometimes get 99, 94, 96, but never 100. I get this behavior on VS2015, clang and gcc.

[Here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/42c1688cdb507372) is an online example.

Comment: I am not sure but maybe you must flush the output stream after each write

Comment: If you're going to write a binary file, use Unformatted Input/Output Functions, not Formatted Input/Output Functions. (So `read` and `write` not extraction and insertion operators.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
ifs >> c
```

skips whitespace per default. Put

```
ifs >> std::noskipws;
```

before the loop to also read whitespace bytes.

---

Also

```
ofs.close(); // not needed?
```

Not needed indeed, the file is closed when the stream goes out of scope.

Comment: Thank you! It is a relief to know this specified behavior. I just wanted direct access to the bytes. Time for me to read `ifstream` documentation again I suppose.